# Handling Orientation in Ios7 for specific ViewControllers

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation

I'm creating a ebook application in which i have only given all orientation's to two of the ViewControllers.

i was abel to successfully set the orientation to the two ViewControllers and perform the Rotation for the first time.but later when i load the view controller with new book the rotation is not working properly.

i used the methods:

```
  -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                           duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
  if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )    {
  //code for landscape
  }
  else{
   //code for protrait.
  }
  }

  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
  } 
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
 }
```

Comment: Did you try `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` in your new viewController?

Comment: that is to set the type of orientations supported rty?

Comment: What do you mean by - "but later when i load the view controller with new book the rotation is not working properly." ?? Are you reloading the page, navigating through the hierarchy or what??

Comment: most of the view's go out of frame.

Comment: Please be more specific in "later when i load the view controller with new book the rotation is not working properly."

Comment: after loading one book in a viewconroller.i go back to the list of books and load another book in the same viewcontroller.the second time  onwards the when rotating the  subview's go out of frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle rotation on your UINavigationControllers, your exact code on a UINavigationController subclass is correct. And make sure your UIViewControllers are set as childViewControllers of your new UINavigationControllers.
And remember you need to set your supported orientations with the key "Supported interface orientations" on your info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SubClass of UINavigationController

@interface BaseNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

```
@implementation BaseNavigationController

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        BOOL shouldAutorotateBool = NO;
        if ([self isRotate]) {
            if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)])
                shouldAutorotateBool =  [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
        }
        return shouldAutorotateBool;
    }


    // iOS6/7 support
    - (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {


        NSUInteger interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

        if ([self isRotate]) {
            if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation)]) {
                interfaceOrientation = [[self.viewControllers lastObject]  preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
            }
        }
        return interfaceOrientation;
    }

    - (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

        UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

        if ([self isRotate]) {
            if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation)]) {
                interfaceOrientation = [[self.viewControllers lastObject]  preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
            }
        }
        return interfaceOrientation;

    }
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        BOOL shouldAutorotateBool = NO;
        if ([self isRotate]) {
            if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)])
                shouldAutorotateBool =  [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
        }

        return shouldAutorotateBool;
    }

    -(BOOL) isRotate
    {
        if ([[self.viewControllers lastObject] isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"VideoVC")]) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }
@end
```

And in that particular viewController:

```
#import "VideoVC.h"

@interface VideoVC ()

@end

@implementation VideoVC
#pragma mark- Methods for device orientation handling
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: i'm not using navigation controller.so is there any way to handle it in viewcontroller itself?

Comment: You can use the above code and hide the navigation in custom navigation class.

Comment: How you load the viewController ? Are you pushing it.....?
Try to Present the viewController and test it

Comment: so instead of pushing it to navigationController we should just [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil]; from viewDidLoad?

Comment: - (IBAction)pushVideoClicked:(id)sender {
    
    VideoVC * obj_VideoVC = [[VideoVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideoVC" bundle:nil];
//    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_VideoVC animated:YES];
    
    [self presentViewController:obj_VideoVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    
}
Try this..

Comment: VideoVC * obj_VideoVC = [[VideoVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideoVC" bundle:nil]; // [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_VideoVC animated:YES]; [self presentViewController:obj_VideoVC animated:YES completion:nil];   this should be done from the navigationcontrollers viewdidload?

Comment: Under Appdelegate: 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.VC = [[BaseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BaseViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.nav = [[BaseNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.VC];
    
    self.window.rootViewController = self.nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

Under BaseViewController class, on button Click.. present the Video ViewController